# Two entities mapped to a single stored procedure in Entity Framework: DB First Approach

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, mapping

I have 2 tables in the DB, namely `Students` and `Class`.
I have created a single `stored procedure`, namely `Update`, to update both the tables.

I have created a WebForms project and have added an `Entity Data Model` via `Database First` approach. Now how do I map the procedure to both the entities?
The entities are not related to each other by any means.

Below is my stored proc and the table skeletons:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[UpdateStudent]
@Id int,
@Name varchar(20),
@City varchar(20),
@ClassId int,
@ClassName varchar(10),
@ClassLocation varchar(10)
as
begin
update Students set Name=@Name, City=@City where Id=@Id
update Class set ClassName=@ClassName, ClassLocation=@ClassLocation where ClassId=@ClassId
end
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Class](
    [ClassID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClassName] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ClassLocation] [varchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Students](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [City] [varchar](20) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Below is my EDMX file:

[image]

Please advise.

Regards

Comment: You should be able to drag the stored procedure into the designer of the entity model

Comment: If I right-click one of the entities, I have the option of mapping it to the stored proc. But since the sp has 2 update statements, the code breaks down.

Comment: If you u go to server explorer in VS connect to your sql instance Database > Stored Procs > YourProc Drag into the Entity designer

Comment: Mr. Bumble Bee: I'm using VS 2012 with EF 5.0...I did as you said.but am unable to drag the sp.any catch involved here? If you wud know

Comment: Have you looked at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx to map right to the  database object ?

Comment: Will have a look..thanks

Comment: But wudnt there be an option to map a single proc to multiple entities?